# Determine whether a modulus function is bijective, and if so find its inverse function. (See picture.)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

It's only part b) I'm struggling with.  I'm not sure how to work with modulus to show the properties I need to to show it's bijective.  Nor am I sure how to work with them to find its inverse function.

[The picture of the question can be found here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPrra.jpg)

Comment: This has nothing to do with group theory. Are you sure the question is in this conext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If $x$ is positive, then $f(x) = 4x^2/2x = 2x$. This yields all the positive even integers. If $x$ is negative, then $f(x) = (-4x^2 -2x)/2x = -2x - 1$. This yields all the positive odd integers.

Comment: Thank you.  I have used this to construct a full mathematical argument as to why the function is surjective.  But I'm unsure as to how to approach the injectivity proof.  And I'm also unsure how to find the inverse function.

Comment: @RCG For injectivity: suppose that $f(x) = f(y)$. Use the expressions above to conclude that $x$ and $y$ must have the same sign, and a fortiori that they must be the same. If you've proven surjectivity then you've already found the inverse: it's the function that maps any element in the codomain to its preimage.